# How I can get the first post from a facebook account/profile as I need to scroll down eternally

Tags: facebook, post, scroll

I want to double check when the activity and what's about it for certain facebook profile, however I already scrolled a lot of times and still more posts are coming and feels like should be another way to get it done... Is there any simpler form to get the Facebook posts from a profile? I'm specially interested in the first ones... Seems hard to get there ans seems silly to be scrolling indefinitely...

The page is this one: https://www.facebook.com/MauticCommunity and I'm interested in the firsts posts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it, but not sure if it is really the last one of if the browser is not loading anything else. I reviewed the Network from the Web Inspector and is not loading/sending more requests when scrolling down.

[image]